# Implement smooth scroll inside the slimScroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling, slimscroll

I am trying to implement smooth mouse wheel scroll inside the slimScroll box/container, I have so far tried many different smooth scrolling plugin, but it either had no effect or removes the scroll all together, I am kind of stuck in here. 
Help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you want an answer, you must provide some code -- or, better yet, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) -- so that we can have some code to play with and see if we can solve your problem for you.

Comment: I can provide the code, but I am not really sure which part, as I am using an external jquery plugin and want to add a feature to it.

I will put it simple.

I am using fullpage.js to create a <section> based website, it allows to have scrollable section using a js library-slimScroll.
Now the scroll inside that slimScroll is the usual scroll, but my client want a smooth mouse wheel scroll.
Tried using many libraries with no effect.

Comment: If you want an answer, I suggest putting in the time to create a simplified jsFiddle environment for others to play with. Expecting readers to do that for you, *and to answer your question also,* is asking a lot.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523732/how-to-animate-slimscroll-using-jquery